# Assign a key to all array values and change each key/pair into a separate array within the array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my input:

`$testKeys = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];`

I want to change this into:

`[['Name' => 'test1'], ['Name' => 'test2'], ['Name' => 'test3'], ...]`

I have tried doing `$testKeys = array_fill_keys($testKeys, 'Name');` But this does not put them into separate arrays and it makes the key/value the opposite of what I want.

Can anyone help me please? The key is always gonna be 'Name', it will always be a single key/value pair in each separate array inside an array.  Thanks.

Comment: You could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do that.

Comment: Hello does this mean I need to create a new function and then use that in array_map? Sorry am bit confused, is it possible I can do it without using custom functions?

Comment: You could use a foreach and create a new array for each entry aswell

Comment: @Remy thank you I have followed your suggestion and it is working now.  I put my comment below what I used please let me know if it's okay;

Comment: Seems good, you don't have to use the reference operator on the values though.

Answer (score 0):

After following suggestions, I found out I can do it like this:

```
foreach ($testKeys as $key => &$value) {
    $value = ['Name' => $value];
    unset($value);
}

// Output: [['Name' => 'test1'], ['Name' => 'test2'], ...]
```

Thank you.